# Python Server With Flutter client

Tags: python, flutter, websocket, server

I am trying to make an application that uses python server but server responded with [Server's respond](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chYLI.png)
in debug console (in flutter)[Flutter debug console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEiUE.png) anyone know why this happens?

Code to send data to server

```
void sendData() async {
  final channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(Uri.parse('ws://$HOST:$PORT'));
  channel.sink.add(
  json.encode('FU'));
}
```

I want to send a message to server

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)